# PyMC: What 's the best way to create an array with a random number of random variables in pymc?

Tags: pymc

Say you have a hierarchical model in which N is given by a Poisson distribution (N ~ Poisson(mu=lambda); prob(N=n)=Poisson(x=n; mu=lambda)), or any other distribution, it doesn't matter. And then you want to create an array with N random variables, say, exponentially distributed: X = (X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) and  X_i ~ Exponential(beta=a_i). What's the best way to do this? (Note that both the dimension and the components are random.)